# PHP, Laravel, Trait Not Found

Tags: php, laravel

**UPDATE**

After too many trials and fails, I noticed that the error is kinda misleading. I go back one of older versions, grab the old files and bring in the newer version one by one. It turned out the error has been thrown when I changed the Publishings.php unlike mentioned in error message.

**UPDATE 2**

These two traits, Posts.php and Publishings.php, use each other mutually. I think it creates some sort of conflict. When I broke the link, everything worked again.

**THE ORIGINAL POST**

I got the weirdest error I have ever faced. I hope someone can help. I have bunch of Traits and all use each other.

```
/app
    /Traits
        /Products.php
        /Publishings.php
        /Posts.php
        /...
```

Publishings.php is used in 5 controller and 2 traits and working normal. But in only one trait, it gives this error:

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Trait "App\Traits\Publishings" not found
```

The trait that throws the error is Posts.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\Publishing;
use App\Traits\Pictures;
use App\Traits\Publishings;
use App\Traits\Videos;
use Carbon\Carbon;

trait Posts
{

    use Pictures, Publishings, Videos;

    public function...

}
```

The error comes from line 12. That line's content is "trait Posts".

HomeController also uses Publishings trait, and when I delete use App\Traits\Publishings, it gives me undefined function error. So HomeController can find Publishings.

I tried clear all caches multiple times. No help. Also, a copy of this app is running in share hosting without any problem. I reinstall fresh copy of Windows 10 yesterday, and my folder structure is kina weird. Even though I can't see any relation, I wonder if my problem can be related with that.

```
C:\Coding\Projects // this is the document root instead of htdocs
C:\Coding\Platforms\Xampp
```

I ran out of ideas. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

This is the namespace of Publishings.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Publishing;
use App\Traits\Pictures;
use App\Traits\Paginate;
use App\Traits\Videos;
use App\Traits\Specs;
use App\Traits\Posts;

trait Publishings
{
    use Posts, Pictures, Paginate, Specs, Videos;

}
```

Comment: what is the conetnt of publishing?

Comment: Be sure your trait name space is correct.

Comment: @Jonnathan I commented out all functions in Publishings trait and the error remains the same. So the error shouldn't be related the content. That file contains 15 functions and 200 lines of code. It's useless to put it here. But if you need to see, sure I can put it here.

Comment: @Sok, I think it's correct. As I said, HomeController can find very same trait without any issue.

Comment: @BülentAkgül It isn't useless to just include the namespace of that file.  Please do that.

Comment: @BülentAkgül This seems likely to be a typo problem; you say `App\Trait\Publishings`, yet all of your namespaced traits use `App\Traits`, not `App\Trait`.

Comment: @Daedalus I included it.

Comment: @Daedalus it was typo just here. I fixed it.

Comment: Please share some code to reproduce the problem - how does that `HomeController` look like?

Answer (score 0):

The folder structure is irrelevant. If you make a typo in the namespace, it will still work as long as you use that same typo in the other files. Double check the namespace.

You said:

> HomeController also uses Publishings trait, and when I delete use App\Trait\Publishings, it gives me undefined function error. So HomeController can find Publishings.

`App\Trait\Publishings` is not the same as `App\Traits\Publishings` !!!

Comment: Folder name is Traits. It was a typo here.